# A subgroup $B$ of an finitely generated group $A$ such that $|A/B| = n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

Let $A$ be a finitely generated, infinite abelian group, and $n$ a positive integer.  Show there exists a subgroup $B$ such that $|A/B| = n$.

I'm trying to use induction on the number of generators of $A$, but I don't know if this is a good approach.  Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Conifold This is for an arbitrary group $A$, not just an example of a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, $A$ is isomorphic to a group $\mathbb{Z}\times A'$, where $A'$ is some abelian group. Hence, $A$ surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}$. As $\mathbb{Z}$ surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the cyclic group of order $n$, it follows that $A$ also surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}_n$. The result then follows by the first isomorphism theorem.

You can actually find the subgroup $B$ if you want, although the question doesn't ask for this: Using the integers in the obvious way to denote the elements of the $\mathbb{Z}$ factor in $\mathbb{Z}\times A'$, so $A=\langle 1, A\rangle$, then $B=\langle n, A'\rangle$.

---

[The last paragraph is potentially ambiguous as there may be lots of $\mathbb{Z}$-factors of $A$. I wrote it like this because I wanted to use additive notation. Multiplicatively, and unambiguously, let $z$ be the generator of the $\mathbb{Z}$-factor in $\mathbb{Z}\times A'$, so $A=\langle z, A\rangle$, and then $B=\langle z^n, A'\rangle$.]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The $k = 1$ case is when $A \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Can you describe the desired subgroup $B$ in this case? Can you modify your argument for the $k$ generator case?

Comment: The subgroup $B$ is certainly $n\mathbb Z$, but for a general $A = gen(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k)$, I don't think $B = gen(na_1, na_2, \ldots, na_k)$ would work, right?  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @gravitybeatle: That wouldn’t work; it would give you $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^k$. But you are close...

Comment: I've changed the $n$ to a $k$ here, as $n$ has a different meaning in the question.